# Boost Converter Design Formulas

Tags: boost, converter

I have a boost converter. 
Vin=10-16V
Vout =23V
Iload=250mA.
Fsw=125kHz

> [NCV3063](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP3063-D.PDF)

I have a Boost converter App note from TI. [Boost Converter TI App note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva372c/slva372c.pdf)

I tried to design my boost converter circuit using the formulas provided from the app note as I was not able to understand the formulas provided in my NCV3063 Boost Converter datasheet.

Can I use the App note formulas to design my boost converter inductor?

Why are there different formulas for the same boost converter topology?

Thanks.

Comment: Bro. generally inductors value are common for very low voltage boost convreter like 4.4, 10uH to 47uH. but when you voltage range is higher formulas are different but vlaue you will get near by .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed that Application note from TI once, back in 3rd semester, worked like a charm.

```
Can I use the App note formulas to design my boost converter inductor?
```

No I would not mix and match two different manufactors design notes.

```
Why are there different formulas for the same boost converter topology?
```

Many ways leads to Rome :) Sorry for the vague answer, I'm not entirely sure.
But I'm fairly confident the result should be the same if its the EXACT same topology.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me which graph in the NCV3063 datasheet I should refer to, to calculate the value of VSWCE for my design input and output?

Comment: 9. VSWCE − Darlington Switch Collector to Emitter Voltage Drop, refer to Figures 7, 8, 9 and 10. depending on your configuration

Comment: but those graphs are given for Vcc=5V. My Vcc is not 5V. It is 10V. and which graph in specific and why?

Comment: If you are trying to use a design that is not meant for your specifications you are in for a bad time :( .. I suggest you write down all your requirements and search for an alternative chip that can live up to those requirements.
http://www.ti.com/product/LM25118 try this .. and use the Design bench tool TI provides.